# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found for pygpu/libgpuarray

Tags: python, opencl, gpu, anaconda, theano

I'm using libgpuarray (openCL) but can't seem to get the GPU working with Theano in anaconda 2. When I try to run the [test](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html) I get:

> ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be
>   imported Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0.dev1-py2.7.egg\theano\gpuarray__init__.py",
>   line 21, in import pygpu File
>   "C:\Users\username\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pygpu-0.2.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pygpu__init__.py",
>   line 7, in from . import gpuarray, elemwise, reduction  ImportError:
>   DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Theano works fine with the cpu. I followed [this](http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html) documentation. I ran the command code "python setup.py build" and "python setup.py install" on setup.py in the libgpuarray folder (after I used cmake to install libgpuarray) to get pygpu and it ran successfully. After running cmake I get the gpuarray.dll file yet this error still occurs. Do I need to do something with it or is there something else happening?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by copying `gpuarray.dll` generated in your build dir into C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: I got to the point a while ago where I found out I had to use the bleeding edge version of theano but it didnt work. Just crashed every time i tried to import theano, with no error message. So I'm not working with this stuff anymore, but if you find out how to make it so the bleeding edge version of theano works on windows 12 for opencl then let me know. Thanks anyway